# How to loop over a multidimensional objectArray with Smarty?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, smarty

In Smarty, how can I iterate over the `sub` value in my second foreach?

```
[test] => stdClass Object
        (
            [parent] => Test
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key1] => Value 1
                            [key2] => Value 2
                        )

                )

        )
        
 {foreach from=$menuList item=menu}
    <li><a href="#">{$menu->name}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {foreach from=$menu->sub key=k item=v}
                <li class="dropdown-submenu" name=>{$v}</li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {/foreach}
 </li>
```

How to print second foreach **key** and **value**?

It print array string only

Comment: Could you [edit] to show what the current output is, and what output you want instead?

Comment: it shows Array....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your "array" is in fact object. You need to convert it to array first to use that function. Here is a function that can do this:

```
function objectToArray($d) {
    if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }
    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}
```

Obviously this is php function, put it in php file or in smarty plugin to be able to access it. Then, here is a function that is using the previous function to deal dinamically with objects, or whatever input is.

```
function smarty_function_tree($params, &$smarty) {
if (!isset($params['level'])) {
    $level = 0;
    } else {
    $level = $params['level'];
}
return tree($params['data'], $level);
}

function tree($data, $level) {
echo '<ul class="level', $level, '">', "\r\n";
$aData = objectToArray($data);
foreach ($aData as $key => $entry) {
    if (is_array($entry)) {
        echo '<li>', $key, '</li>', "\r\n";
        tree($entry, $level+1);
    } else {
        echo '<li>', $key, ' = ', $entry, '</li>', "\r\n";
    }
}
    echo '</ul>', "\r\n";
}
```

Create a plugin called accordingly to function name, then you can use it in template like this:

```
{tree data=$yourObject}
```

or

```
{tree data=$yourArray}
```

Edit: you also can use litlebit of css to indent the output of the tree function:

```
.level0 {
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.level1 {
    text-indent: 40px;
}

.level2 {
    text-indent: 60px;
}

.level3 {
    text-indent: 80px;
}

.level4 {
    text-indent: 100px;
}

.level5 {
    text-indent: 120px;
}

.level6 {
    text-indent: 140px;
}

.level7 {
    text-indent: 160px;
}

.level8 {
    text-indent: 180px;
}

.level9 {
    text-indent: 200px;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you know `key1` and `key2` you can do:

```
{foreach from=$menu->sub key=k item=v}
    key1 = {$v.key1}, key2 = {$v.key2}
{/foreach}
```

output:

```
key1 = value1, key2 = value2
```

***In your example***

```
{foreach from=$menuList item=menu}
    <li><a href="#">{$menu->name}</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          {foreach from=$menu->sub key=k item=v}
                <li class="dropdown-submenu" name="{$v.key1}"></li>
          {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {/foreach}
 </li>
```

---

If you don't know key you need another *loop*:

```
{foreach from=$menu->sub key=k item=v}
    {foreach from=$v key=u item=i}
        {$u} = {$i},
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

output:

```
key1 = value1, key2 = value2,
```

If you have an *Object* you use `->`. If you have and *Array* use `.`or `[]`